# Is it called a water shadow?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

The sun light or bulb light shines into the water in a pool and causes some moving pictures on the wall or ceiling.

[image]

**Is it called a water shadow?**

Comment: I don't think there is a specific word.  I think part of your misunderstanding is the meaning of bóng - which (wiktionary says) can be used in viet for both a shadow and reflection.  In English, if the sun shines on a tree and then the dark shape on the ground where the sun is blocked is a "shadow", but the picture of the tree you see in a lake or in a mirror is a reflection.

Comment: However  "water reflection" isn't the answer.  I would use "the dancing pattern of light (reflected from the surface of the water)"

Comment: Water does not cast shadows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such moving patterns are called **reflections**.

[image]

Comment: OP's *specific* type are often referred to as [***dappled** reflections*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dappled+reflections%22) As opposed to [***dappled sunlight***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dappled+sunlight%22) which might simply be caused by overhead leaves moving in the wind, with no water or reflections involved.